# C# Foreach with condition check every time

Tags: c#, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a problem with condition check every cycle in foreach loop

my code looks like this

```
public void data_comm(string comm)
    {
        foreach (Element command in SortedList) if (comm == "OK")
            {
                comm = "";
                //do stuff
             {
     }
```

Where `SortedList` is list of objects made of some strings and doubles

`comm` is used like that. It is string sent by arduino and will be used by `SetText` or if `comm = "OK"` it will send data to arduino depending on object in list

```
 public void Read()
    {
        while (port.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                string message = port.ReadLine();

                SetText(message);
                data_comm(message);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }
```

So it seems, that after the loop runs once it ill keep variable `comm = ""`
and what i want is to check every loop if its `"OK"`

And without formating `comm` it just stays in `foreach` loop
Is there a way, how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Add braces around the `foreach`.

Comment: Um... the foreach is iterating with `comma` (notice the comm**a**), and the if checks `comm`... is that intentional? I'm not sure what you are trying to do, `comm` can only be one thing, it doesn't change with each loop.

Comment: I"m lost. `comm` is an argument to the method so why do you need to see if it's value is still `OK` on each iteration? And if you change it in the loop then it will not be `OK` anymore. Try to explain again what you are trying to do please.

Comment: can you post the structure of StoredList please ? because you said it's a list of objects and if you want to check the string inside that object you should be doing something like : `comma.someString = " "`

Comment: Can you explain, what do you want a bit clearer? Right now you have a function param, that you do check for every iteration of the loop. Maybe you can show how that comm is changed, other then being set to ""?

Comment: Post a more complete code (this one has unclosed blocks, no example on how the function is called, no definition of Element). It's also a bit unclear on what you want to do and why.

Comment: well, this program stores list of objects, and sends it to Arduino. after arduino receives data and do its part it sends OK. And i did not came with better idea on how to send objects

Answer (score -1):

You probably need something like this:

```
public void data_comm(string comm)
{
    foreach (Element command in SortedList.Where(_ => comm == "OK"))
    {
        comm = "";
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

However, the more standard way is to call `break` when you need to quit the loop.

```
public void data_comm(string comm)
{
    foreach (Element command in SortedList)
    {
        comm = "";
        break;
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Take these two examples:

(1)

```
var xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var comm = "OK";

foreach (var x in xs.Where(_ => comm == "OK"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    if (x == 2)
    {
        comm = "";
    }
}
```

(2)

```
var xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var comm = "OK";

foreach (var x in xs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    if (x == 2)
    {
        comm = "";
        break;
    }
}
```

The latter is the more common way to code this scenario.

Comment: `SortedList.Where(_ => comm == "OK"))` makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Because the condition isn't applied to elements on the list. The only thing that could make sense `if (comm == "OK") return;` before the foreach

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - It doesn't have to reference the elements in the list. That's why I used `_` as the variable - to signal that it was ignored. This just allows the loop to finish early. It's why I said that the `break` keyword is the more usual way to do this.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I think I answered the question in exactly the way that the OP asked for.